# android studio accepted importing inner class?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

i have this code :

```
package com.example.android.cars.data;
    public final class DataBaseContract {


        public static final class Table1Entry implements BaseColumns {

            /** Name of database table for cars */
            public final static String TABLE_NAME = "car";


        }

    }
```

i use `Table1Entry` in another class with different package and i `import` the nested class like this
`import` `com.example.android.cars.data.DataBaseContract.Table1Entry;`

this allow me to use nested class without outer prefix `DataBaseContract`,

my question is when i removed `static` from nested class the code still work, how can this accrue in this case !! i need outer instance to access it!!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you would need an instance of the outerclass **IF** you wanted to access instance methods of the inner class. However from your example you are only accessing static fields, therefore because the field is static you can access it directly like you explained.